# typedef typename in templated class

Tags: c++, clang

I have this class:

```
template<Foo::Bar::EType ID,typename TYPE,int NBR>
class NumType            
{    
public:
    typedef TYPE                ElementType;
}
```

In another area of code I use the ElementType

```
class VectorType : public NumType<ID,TYPE,NBR>
{            
public:            
    typedef const ElementType* ValueType;
};
```

but I am getting the error:

> Error 3 error : unknown type name 'ElementType'

Does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: I tried this but get the error: Error  error : 'NumType' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration. Is this something unrelated?

Comment: @marsh `NumType` is class template, not class.

Comment: @kfsone I'm deleting my comment as misleading what I really meant lies in Brian's answer.

Comment: @PcAF thanks that did it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a base class is dependent, its scope is not searched during unqualified name lookup. To solve this, explicitly name the base class by writing `typename NumType<ID,TYPE,NBR>::ElementType` instead of just `ElementType`, which makes it a dependent name and forces its lookup to be postponed to instantiation time, at which point it will be found.

The desired type can also be named by `typename VectorType::ElementType` or `typename VectorType::NumType::ElementType`, although these could be less clear to the reader of the code.

Comment: @marsh Please post the shortest self-contained example that reproduces the error.

Comment: `NumType` is not class, it's class template, in order to achive what Brian showed, you have to use `NumType<something,something,something>`

Comment: Note however, as I said, `typename VectorType::NumType::ElementType` does work, even though the template arguments are omitted. It finds the *injected-class-name* for `NumType`.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that's possible, I think that he probably forgot to add `typename` , anyway why when I write just `typename NumType::ElementType` (wihtout `VectorType`) it doesn't work? It is qualified-id, so why it doesn't find *injected-class-name* ?

Comment: @PcAF The *injected-class-name* belongs to the scope of the class itself, so if `NumType`'s scope is already not being searched, then its *injected-class-name* can't be found. `NumType` is on the very left so its lookup is unqualified.